# Can a SMPS be turned off to increase overall efficiency for low power applications?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

I am designing a wearable low power application. Most of the time (>99%) the application uses less than 50µA. With such a low current all switch mode power supplies I could find get really inefficient. At this rate most energy is used just to keep the oscillator running.  My idea was to place a big 330µF cap after the power supply. Now I can turn off the power supply until it drops 1V in approximately 1,0s. After which I can turn it on again and charge the capacitor with a higher efficiency (higher current). Could this be a valid method to increase the efficiency of a digital circuit?

My thought is that the dU/dT  would still be low, and won’t cause any problems as long as the components  have a corresponding  VCC range.

Comment: Yep. So-called pulse skipping feature. Also, consider hysteretic converters for which this is inherent. Simpler too.

Comment: The energy efficiency to restore a capacitor voltage from a voltage source is 50%. And it doesn't matter whether the voltage source is a battery or switching regulator. I think you need to forget about "efficiency" as a valid figure of merit and concentrate on minimizing the average current drained from the battery.

Comment: @Andyaka a typical switching regulator is not a voltage source in its actual instantaneous operation.

Comment: It can be regarded so if there it still uses an output capacitor but, I do take your point that the inductor provides the output capacitor with theoretically 100% energy transfer.

Comment: In this case, the capacitor the OP wants to provide *is* the effective output capacitor.  I do think their numbers are a bit extreme in capacitor size and timeframe.  But what they are wanting to do is in fact the shape of an idea in actual use.

Comment: Not entirely if this is true: *My idea was to place a big 330µF cap after the power supply. Now I can turn off the power supply until it drops 1V in approximately 1,0s.* - that would still imply an output capacitor connected to the power supply - OK it might be 10 uF and in that case it is negligible.

Comment: Also consider designing *for* the battery, such that a switcher isn't needed.

Comment: In many cases such as this, a linear regulator may well be *more* efficient (in terms of overall battery drain). There are always trade-offs and that is application specific. For the 1% of time your design is not in low power mode, what is the load current?

Comment: @Andyaka  Even if charged through a  resistor, 50% efficiency only applies if the capacitor is charged from zero. If the capacitor is cycled between 90% and 100%, as it may be in a typical burst or skipping supply, the efficiency is close to 100%

Answer (score 1):

Most low-power-conscious power supplies have power-saving features included, similar to what you have described. There are some considerations to keep in mind.

All switching power supplies have a finite start-up time. The power rails need to be steady, reference voltages need to establish and stabilize, and the switching converter needs to ramp (or soft-start) in order to avoid large stresses on the powertrain elements. A total turn-off usually means a recovery time of hundreds of milliseconds, which could be bad if there's a sudden surge in the load. (In your case, not so much, but power IC designers need to consider all possibilities).

Another method is to keep the controller alive, but simply stop operating the powertrain. The controller will still consume power but there is a net savings as the powertrain devices are not switching all the time.

- Pulse-skipping: the setpoint remains fixed and the controller occasionally misses pulses (less output ripple, but possibly noisier)
- Hysteretic control - the controller deliberately nudges the setpoint up and down so that the pulses come in smooth bunches instead of spurious skips (the voltage will slew up and down in a sawtooth pattern)

All basic PWM controllers will pulse-skip by nature of the control algorithm (PWM width proportional to the error voltage: if error voltage > reference voltage, PWM = 0%). So this isn't so much a power-saving feature, rather how the controller inherently behaves at light loads. Hysteretic regulation is closer to the spirit of your idea - let the output sag a little to the lower threshold, then send some pulses to recover to the slightly higher threshold.

In both of these cases, because the controller remains active, there is a faster recovery if there is some input disturbance or load step.

Keeping the pulses more regular results in a smoother output, which your load would likely appreciate. Also, when there is a lot of capacitance on the output, keeping the pulses regular also avoids a large inrush of current being drawn when the capacitor is depleted and needs to be recharged, which is good for component stress and for EMI.